# Azure Function Queue Trigger Connection - can I set this from a variable or specifically Azure Application Configuration?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-configuration

As simple as I can put it, I have the following:

```
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("order-new", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
```

Is there any way I can do something like:

```
 public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("order-new", Connection = _connection)]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
```

Where the Connection is passed in as a variable?  I have access to the value in the constructor, it is from Azure Application Configuration service.  I am just trying not to have to change settings in more than one place.  Thank you.

Update:
I have actually found a way to get the actual string (not a variable) into the method arguments, but the "Connection" input is interpreting it as a variable it needs to look for, not the literal string which is the connection itself.

Update #2:
I think I have it figured out, will write it up when I get a chance (@baum-mit-augen actually deleted the post that led me there).

Comment: I am having a hard understanding your question. In general you inject IConfiguration and it gives you azure app configuration. But you want it by variable?

Comment: Not necessarily, as far as I know, I need to get it into the arguments constructor of the 'Run' method (Connection="xxx"), if there is a another way to specify this, that would work as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have an Application Setting set to your Azure Application Configuration connection string, in this example I have it named **APP_CONFIG_CONNECTION**

To do this in Visual Studio, right click the project, then click properties:
[image]

In your Azure Function, it will be in the configuration section:
[image]

Install the needed package:
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration -Version 4.2.1

Add a Startup.cs file if it does not already exist:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            string cs = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_CONFIG_CONNECTION");
            builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(cs);
        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddAzureAppConfiguration();
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your functions, you can refer to your config variables by path.

Examples

```
[return: Queue(queueName: "%Some:Path:QueueName%", Connection = "Some:Path:ConnectionString")]
```

or

```
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger(queueName: "%Some:Path:QueueName%", Connection = "Some:Path:ConnectionString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
```

BOOM, no settings in your project outside of the connection string.  Notice that the queueName variable is surround with '%' as it is a literal, while the Connection is not as it is a variable. You can also access other variables via dependency injection as well:

```
    private readonly SomeApiClient _api;

    public My_QueueTrigger(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var config = configuration.Get<AppSettings>();
        _api = new SomeApiClient (new
        {
            ApiUrl = config.ApiUrl,
            AuthUrl = config.AuthUrl,
            ClientId = config.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = config.ClientSecret,
            Roles = new[] { ApiRole.FullAccess }
        });
    }
```

Hope this is useful to someone else out there.

Comment: I'm trying to get this working - I do use dep injection for other settings I keep in the App Config service, which works fine - but the QueueTrigger seems to trying to initialize before the FunctionStartup runs, and it's throwing a warning on startup that it cannot find a Connection string name in local.settings.json

EDIT: Ignore me - there's a further "warning" further down that the queue is using a modified key that matches the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

> can I set this from a variable or specifically Azure Application
> Configuration?

No, It actually gets the value from the environment variable.

But if it is really necessary, you can import the required configuration into the environment variable [when the function starts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection).

From your question description, it seems you are developing on Visual Studio, so just set settings in `local.settings.json` when develop on local. And upload the settings easily by using this:

[image]

Comment: The whole point I am trying to accomplish is to not have _any_ settings local to the project itself.  I want all settings to be on the Azure Application Configuration service.  I suppose I could script out the replacement upon a deployment job, but there has to be a better way, right?

Comment: this is incorrect information, it is possible as shown in my solution